# Subtend perpendicular at origin

Tags: circles, conic-sections

**Question:**

> The locus of the foot of perpendicular, from the origin to chords of circle $x^2+y^2-4x-6y-3=0$, which subtend a right angle at the origin, is what?

**My attempt:**

Assume a chord $y=mx+c$. Homogenize it with the given circle and $\text{coeff of } x^2+\text{coeff of } y^2=0$ for subtending right angle at origin. We get a relation in $m$ and $c$ as $2c^2+4mc-6c=3\cdot(1+m^2)$.

Now, the foot of perpendicular $(x_0,y_0)$ on $y-mx-c=0$ from origin is given by $$\frac{x_0}{-m}=y_0=-\frac{-c}{1+m^2}$$
implying $$x_0=\frac{-mc}{1+m^2},y_0=\frac{c}{1+m^2}$$

Now, how do I find relation in $x_0$ and $y_0$ by eliminating $m$ and $c$. I am stuck here.

**UPDATE:**

[image]

Chord $BC$ subtends right angle at the origin. Point $E$ is the foot of origin on the chord. We want the locus of all such $E$.

Comment: I don't understand "the foot of perpendicular, from the origin to chords of circle".  Are you dropping a line vertically from the end of the chord to the $x$ axis?  Then I don't understand the angle at the origin.  Please draw a picture and show some chord and the point it produces.

Comment: @RossMillikan Thanks for helping! There wasn't any picture given in the question. I'll try draw my interpretation of the question.

Comment: @RossMillikan Added, please have a look.

Comment: Thank you for the figure.  The problem seems to ask for a right angle at the origin, which I don't see.  I was hoping the figure would clarify that.  Given any chord we could draw a perpendicular from the origin to the chord, so the answer here would be the projection of the circle on the $x$ axis.  The complexity of the wording seems to me to indicate there is more going on, but I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: @RossMillikan " The problem seems to ask for a right angle at the origin, which I don't see." But isn't the chord $BC$ subtending a right angle $BOC$ at the origin?

Comment: I don't see the foot of the perpendicular here or know what that is.  As drawn we are asking for the chords that have ends on the two axes and this is the only one.  For most circles there won't be any.

Comment: @RossMillikan "I don't see the foot of the perpendicular here or know what that is" The foot of perpendicular from origin on the chord BC is E. "As drawn we are asking for the chords that have ends on the two axes and this is the only one" I drew just one chord for the sake of simplicity. There will be more such chords (which subtend right angle at the origin), and we want the locus of the foots of perpendicular from origin on all these chords.

Comment: The right angle you show is at $E$, not at the origin.  For any chord you can draw a perpendicular from the origin to the chord.  "Foot of perpendicular" indicates to me dropping a line from some point to an axis.  I am trying to understand what point we drop the perpendicular from.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70755/discussion-between-gaurang-tandon-and-ross-millikan).

Comment: @GaurangTandon, $$\dfrac{y_0}{x_0}=?$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee $=\frac{-1}{m}$. But why does it matter?

Comment: @GaurangTandon, Then we can replace this value of $m$ to find $c$ in terms of $x_0,y_0$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I don't think that will yield a new solvable equation. Can you please show me exactly the steps? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the expressions you found for $x_0$ and $y_0$ one also gets:
$$
x_0^2+y_0^2={c^2\over1+m^2}.
$$
From ${c^2+2mc-3c\over1+m^2}={3\over2}$ we have then:
$$
{c^2+2mc-3c\over1+m^2}=x_0^2+y_0^2-2x_0-3y_0={3\over2}.
$$
That is the equation of a circle, centered at $\left(1,{3\over2}\right)$ and of radius ${\sqrt{19}\over2}$, which is then the desired locus.

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help! Though I don't understand what exactly have you shown. Please write a word or two. Thank you!

Comment: See if what I added is of help.

Comment: I slightly changed the derivation, to make it clearer.

Comment: Wow, it's wonderful! Thanks a lot! :D PS: The GIF is really awesome, which software did you use to make it?

Comment: I used GeoGebra, a free but very powerful piece of software.

Comment: I've been using for ages now and never knew it can even animate the things it draws :P Great to know!